# Getting a JSON from a website Node JS

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, https

So I'm fairly new to node js, and am having trouble wrapping my head around asynchronous programming.  I'm trying to get a JSON from a website and pass it to a variable for use later, to test I have been using this code:

```
var https = require("https");
var a;
function getter(url){
  var request = https.get(url, function(response){
    var body = "";
    response.on("data", function(chunk){
      body += chunk;
    });
    response.on("end", function(){
      if(response.statusCode === 200){
        try{
          a = JSON.parse(body);
        }catch(err){
          console.log(err);
        }
      }
   })
 })
};
getter('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY');
console.log(a);
```

When I run this I get a as undefined, which seems to make sense from what I've read.  But I'm unclear as to what to do from here.  How would I go about passing this JSON into a variable?

Comment: just move your `console.log` inside the response on-end, and you should get your results displayed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323

Answer (score 0):

`http.get` is asynchronous and executes the event handlers when the events occur. When you call `getter()` this function immediately returns, ie it does not wait for the events and the next statement `console.log(a)` is executed.

Furthermore, js is single threaded, and the current execution stack is never interrupted for any other event/callback or whatsoever. So the event handlers can only run if the current execution has come to an end, ie contains noch more statements. Thus, your `console.log()` will always be executed before any eventhandler of the request, thus `a` is still undefined.

If you want to continue after the request finished, you have to do it from the eventhandler.

See this excellent presentation for some more details https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ